# Grails FindWhere and BetweenDate

Tags: grails

With Grails i can do the following to query the db:

```
...
channel.findAllByTitle("CNN")
..
and
channel.findAllByDateBetween(new Date(), new Date() + 2)
..
```

but how can i combine both in a findWhere method?

```
channel.findAllWhere(title: "CNN", ... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a dynamic finder, but you can do it with a criteria query like this

```
Channel.withCriteria {
  eq('title', 'CNN')
  'between'('date', new Date(), new Date() +1)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not at my workstation, (and cannot verify that this is correct) but from the docs it looks like you should be able to accomplish this by using the boolean 'And' as a part of your dynamic finder.

Check the bottom of this page: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html
And here, under 'Boolean Logic': [http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4.1 Dynamic Finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders)

Something like this may work:

`channel.findAllByTitleAndDateBetween("CNN", new Date(), new Date() + 2)`

Otherwise, criterias should do what you want. I notice that you mention wanting to use findAllWhere (not findAllBy), but I'm assuming what you care about is the result set. Feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Grails 2 (currently at RC3), you can try something with the new ['where' method](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC3/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries):

```
def titleQuery = channel.where {
   title = "CNN"
}

Channel channel = titleQuery.find()
```

or

```
def betweenQuery = channel.where {
   (date >= new Date() && date <= new Date() + 2)
}
def results = betweenQuery.list(max: 10)
```